# Only one data store localStorage JSON data using AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a problem in store localStorage JSON feeds its stores only one data. When I add more data, it shows only one. Please help me!

**Stored Values**

```
var fav_game = [{
    id   : "1212",
    name : "Cricket"
  }];
```

**Store LocalStorage Data**

```
window.localStorage['favgame'] = JSON.stringify(fav_game);
var favgame = JSON.parse(window.localStorage['favgame'] || '{}');
```

**Get Local Storage Items:**

```
$scope.favgame = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('fav_game')) || [];
console.log(localStorage['favgame']);
```

Comment: Where is your code to add more values? Currently you are storing a JSONArray in localStorage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var fav_game = [{ id : "1212", name : "Cricket" }];
window.localStorage['favgame'] = JSON.stringify(fav_game);
function addValue(key,val){
  temp = [];
  tmp = localStorage.getItem(key);
  if(tmp != null){
    temp.push(JSON.parse(tmp));
    temp.push(val);
    window.localStorage['favgame'] = JSON.stringify(temp)
  }
}
addValue('favgame','here your valid data')
```

Comment: Now i have a small problem.. if i add two data in json.. it's stores json on localstorage in a correct format. if i add more then two data it crashes the json format like [ [ {} , {} ] , {} ].. Please help me..

Comment: var fav_game = [{ id : "1212", name : "Cricket" }];
window.localStorage['favgame'] = JSON.stringify(fav_game);
function addValue(key,val){
  temp = [];
  tmp = localStorage.getItem(key);
  if(tmp != null){
    tmp = JSON.parse(tmp)
    for(i=0;i<=tmp.length;i++){
      temp.push(tmp[i])
    }
    temp.push(val);
    window.localStorage['favgame'] = JSON.stringify(temp)
  }
}

Comment: Thank You! Friend.. It's works fine.. but it creates null when add second data. Like [ {..},null,{..},null,{..}].

Comment: Hi Friend, I used the for loop like (i=0;i<tmp.length;i++) remove the equal symbol.. it works fine..